# How to find if an operator is the tensor product of more lower dimensional operators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-computation

In quantum computation and quantum information it is very common to use e.g. the effect of a Hadamard matrix $H$ over $2n$ spins. Using (I think it is called the Kroenecker product in mathematical literature) the tensor product $\otimes$, one can write the Hadamard matrix for example for two spins as

$$
H\otimes H.
$$

I want to ask precisely the opposite question. Is there a theorem(s) that ensures that, e.g. $M\in U(4)$ could be written as

$$
M = M_1\otimes M_2,
$$

where (perhaps) $M_i\in U(2)$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199013/testing-for-decomposable-tensors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rich culture of 4-way arrays, that is square matrices whose elements are square matrices, but I am only a physicist, so I can mention what we mugs in the trenches do faced with these problems, routinely.

Assume, first, as you did for your 4×4 matrix, that it is of the form $M\otimes m$ for *M* and *m* diagonalizable  2×2 matrices--no preteses of generality here. That is, it diagonalizes to the 4×4 diagonal matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
      A&0\\
      0&B
    \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
      a&0\\
      0&b
    \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
      Aa&0&0&0\\
      0&Ab&0&0 \\
0&0&Ba&0 \\
0&0&0&Bb 
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its eigenvalues are not independent, but satisfy the condition $\lambda_1 \lambda_4=\lambda_2 \lambda_3 $.
A similarity transformation of this 4×4 matrix, however, may permute these eigenvalues, and hence sour this relation.

So, given a 4×4 matrix you can diagonalize, it suffices if the above condition on eignevalues is satisfied, but is not really necessary: *if* you found such a pairing among *any* two pairs, you might go backwards, rearrange them in such a desirable ordering as above, incorporate the permuting matrices into the original diagonalizing transformation, and be done.  You might pick a simple example of Pauli matrices. In physics, [Dirac's $\gamma^\mu$ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) are routinely represented and handled this way.

I'd be shocked if multilinear many-array people did not have elegant schemes for this sort of thing, but, here, this is what the grunts do.